# SOAP Authentication Android

Tags: android, soap

I am trying to hit this services but this gives me html reponse please help me where i am wrong
any help is really very help ful

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
    java.net.URL u;
    u = new java.net.URL("http://sdservices.iyogi.net/iyogi/webservicesnonrestv5/toolbarwebservices.asmx");

   URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://sdservices.iyogi.net/SD/ToolbarService.svc/GetProductSettings?SubscriptionCode=W101982488");
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
          inputStreamToString(is);

gives HTML in response:(

Comment: what is the html you are getting?

Comment: thanks for ur reply <html>    <head><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="/iyogi/webservicesnonrestv5/toolbarwebservices.asmx?disco" />    <style type="text/css">            BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 

this is what i am getting
thanks for ur prec reply
please help on this

Comment: I tried accessing the url: http://sdservices.iyogi.net/SD/ToolbarService.svc/GetProductSettings?SubscriptionCode=W101982488 and got a username/password screen, are you sure the subscriptionCode is correct?

Comment: how did you get user name and pass word screen that is what i need

Comment: we will have got one link in response and when you wil open that link that will be kogin screen right.. anyway watever you have got can you please show me how did you do that thanks :)

Comment: jus take the url of the SoapAction and put it in a browser: http://sdservices.iyogi.net/SD/ToolbarService.svc/GetProductSettings?SubscriptionCode=W101982488